# Move the file from one directory to multiple sub-folders

Tags: python

I want to move the video files from 1 folder to individual sub-folders

I made the script for making video from frames. It creates multiple videos properly but only at 1 particular path. Below is the code

```
def frames_to_video(detected_object_input,video_op,fps):

    folders=glob(detected_object_input)
    img_list=[]
    frame_array=[]

    for folder in folders:
        folder_name=os.path.basename(folder)
        vid_ext=".mp4"
        vid_name = folder_name+vid_ext
        final_op=video_op+"\\"+vid_name
        #print(final_op)

        for f in glob(folder+"/*jpg"):
            img_list.append(f)

        for i in range(len(img_list)):
            filename = img_list[i]
            img=cv2.imread(img_list[i])
            height,width,layers=img.shape
            size=(width,height)
            print(filename)
            frame_array.append(img)

            out = cv2.VideoWriter(final_op,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),fps,size)

            for i in range(len(frame_array)):
                out.write(frame_array[i])
            out.release()


detected_object_input= ("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs\\*")
video_op= ("C:\\new_multi_cat\\models\\research\\object_detection\\my_imgs")
fps= 2
frames_to_video(detected_object_input, video_op, fps)
```

Suppose there is folder X. It has multiple sub-folders like A,B,C. My code makes video files as per the names of the folder i.e videoA, videoB, videoC,etc. But these videos are created in folder X. I want these video files to be created in their respective sub-folders like videoA inside sub-folder A, videoB inside sub-folder B,etc

Comment: Have you tried using "/" instead of "\\" or r"/"?

Comment: @mazunki where exactly? while assigning the value to variable final_op? Actually i tried using "/" but the result was still the same

Comment: You're using Windows' slashing standard, and backslashing them in Python strings to output a single \. Using raw strings `r"like t\his\ one"` prevents parsing backslashes. Alternatively, use /, which is the recommended cross-platform standard.

Comment: This is happening because of the use of base name. The use of relative path must solve the issue.

Comment: Try using `os.path.relpath(folder, video_op)` instead of `os.path.basename(folder)`

Comment: @VigneshBayariR. Doesn't work. It creates the video files in folder X only again. os.path.basename was used just to extract the name of the folder

Comment: @mazunki Using "/" also creates the video files in folder X only not inside the sub-folders of X